# Sorted Objected based on nested object value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object that I would like to sort based on the votes that it has, and then map over the new / sorted object.

```
const data = {
  "comment-1508872637211" : {
    "description" : "Blah",
    "votes" : 1
  },
  "comment-1508872675949" : {
    "description" : "Question",
    "votes" : 11
  },
  "comment-1508898578089" : {
    "description" : "whatever\n",
    "votes" : 5
  },
  "comment-1508898637092" : {
    "description" : "new",
    "votes" : 15
  },
  "comment-1508900306998" : {
    "description" : "baj",
    "votes" : 0
  }
}

console.log(data);

const sortedOnVotes = Object.entries(data);

console.log(sortedOnVotes);

// This is the part I'm getting hung up on
const newDataObject = sortedOnVotes.map(([key, value]) => value).sort();

console.log(newDataObject)
```

Ultimately I would love for this new object to still retain the comment-### key and be filtered based on the amount of votes that it has. For example the newDataObject should return something like this:

```
const newDataObject = {
          "comment-1508900306998" : {
            "description" : "baj",
            "votes" : 0
          },
          "comment-1508872637211" : {
            "description" : "Blah",
            "votes" : 1
          },
          "comment-1508898578089" : {
            "description" : "whatever\n",
            "votes" : 5
          },
          "comment-1508872675949" : {
            "description" : "Question",
            "votes" : 11
          }
          "comment-1508898637092" : {
            "description" : "new",
            "votes" : 15
          }

}
```

I think I'm on the right track by using  `Object.values` or  `Object.entries` but I'm really getting hung up on it.

Any help would really be appreciated, thanks!

https://codepen.io/MathiasaurusRex/pen/RLzYVV

Comment: javascript object can be sorted, move them to array if you need to sort

Comment: Use `lodash/sort`, easy to use and simple to configure. See [lodash](https://lodash.com/) here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write the logic to sort the arrays using the `sort()` function like below-

```
const data = {
  "comment-1508872637211" : {
    "description" : "Blah",
    "votes" : 1
  },
  "comment-1508872675949" : {
    "description" : "Question",
    "votes" : 11
  },
  "comment-1508898578089" : {
    "description" : "whatever\n",
    "votes" : 5
  },
  "comment-1508898637092" : {
    "description" : "new",
    "votes" : 15
  },
  "comment-1508900306998" : {
    "description" : "baj",
    "votes" : 0
  }
}

console.log(data);

const sortedOnVotes = Object.entries(data);

console.log(sortedOnVotes);

var result = sortedOnVotes.sort(function(a,b) {
  return a[1].votes - b[1].votes;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like this is getting it sorted for me.

Im still curious if I could get it back into the same format as it was originally as an object with a key and an object value pair.

With your answer it's an array of array.